# Xcode 14.2 Unable to close provisioning ledger entry because not all of its subentries are closed

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-command-line-tools

Xcode 14.2 command line tools archive failed.

```
xcodebuild -allowProvisioningUpdates \
-workspace $WORKSPACE \
-scheme $SCHEME \
archive \
-configuration Release \
-archivePath $ARCHIVEPATH \
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \
EXCLUDED_ARCHS="" | xcpretty;
```

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For whom might facing the problem:
This might be the update that required the "-sdk" flag to avoid the error.
i.e.

```
-sdk iphoneos
```